# angular - failing to bind element's ng-show inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

There is a panel for each contact. I want to show the remove button on a specific panel only when the user mouse over that same panel.

```
...
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="contact1 in Contacts">
                <div class="panel panel-success" ng-mouseenter="{{contact1.id}}=true" ng-mouseleave="{{contact1.id}}=false)">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <a href="#" ng-show="{{contact1.id}}" ng-click="Remove($index)">REMOVE BUTTON</a>
                    </div>
...
```

I cant get the reason why this code doesnt work.

Comment: You don't need `{{ }}`, `ng-show = "contact1.id" ` will be enought.

Comment: but if i remove the {{}} , the content of the id will change. i dont want to keeo there a bool. there is a number inside

Comment: Then use an other var. Something like `contact1.isShow = true`/`contact1.isShow = false` and then `ng-show="contact1.isShow"`

Comment: i thought of that but I think its not a good way to solve this. IsShow has nothing to do with the Contact obs. Contact obs has ID,NAME and PHONE.

Comment: Erase the `id` with a boolean isn't really better .... Moreover, this is only for your interface. This data won't be store anyway, you just use it for controlling the view. Nothing wrong on it.

Comment: right this as an answer so I can mark this as answered. btw thanks very much for your help. I didnt know that it would not save in the object.

Comment: explanation done in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 things in your code that can create problem. First of all, `ng-show` / `ng-mouseneter` / `ng-mouseleave` need an expression. So you don't need to put the `{{ }}`.

But it wasn't the only one problem. The fact is you were using your `id` to manage the show property of your item. But this expression need a boolean and you can't just erase your `id` with a boolean like in `ng-mouseneter`. To do so, you have to use an other attribute in your item, `isShow` for example. This will keep your id safe and you will be able to manage your view with it.

So, it give something like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="contact1 in Contacts">
    <div class="panel panel-success" ng-mouseenter="contact1.isShow = true" ng-mouseleave="contact1.isShow = false">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a href="#" ng-show="contact1.isShow" ng-click="Remove($index)">REMOVE BUTTON</a>
        </div>
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from your assignment statements.

The brackets are to render a variable.  Since you're assigning, instead of `ng-mouseenter="{{contact1.id}}=true"` you'll want to do `ng-mouseenter="contact1.id=true"`

You're previous code was the equivalent of writing something like `null=true`, or whatever value was already assigned to contact.id.  The new code assigns contact.id to the value you specified.

EDIT:  You can just use a local variable.

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="contact1 in Contacts">
  <div class="panel panel-success" ng-mouseenter="showButton=true" ng-mouseleave="showButton=false">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a href="#" ng-show="showButton" ng-click="Remove($index)">REMOVE BUTTON</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if i remove the {{}} , the content of the id will change. i dont want to keeo there a bool. there is a number inside

Comment: Then why in the world are you using that property to show and hide your button?  You can just stick a local variable in there, `ng-mouseenter="removeShowing=true"` and `ng-show="removeShowing"`

Comment: there is a panel for each contact. i want to show the remove button on a specific panel only when the user mouse over that same panel. from your last solution, my code will show all remove buttons on all panels after i mouse over some random panel.

Comment: @StavAlfi try it.  Since your declaring the variable in an ng-repeat, it is local and will be declared and separate for every 'panel'.  It works I promise

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see a working example, but for the start the angular directives you've used require an expressions, so try removing the `{{}}` from `ng-mouseenter, ng-mouseleave and ng-show`.

So, it should be like `ng-show="contact1.id"`. 
Try applying this. Hope it works for you.

Comment: but if i remove the {{}} , the content of the id will change. i dont want to keeo there a bool. there is a number inside

Comment: Like @ErikAGriffin mentioned, you can achieve the desired effect locally with a local variable that you toggle with those angular directives.